# Tab bar not showing in activity

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a tab bar that I want to add to multiple activities. I have a `TabController.java` which looks like this

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class TabController extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabcontroller);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();           
    Intent intent;  

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Help.class);  
    TabSpec specHelp = tabHost.newTabSpec("Help").setIndicator("Help")  
                  .setContent(intent);  


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Services.class);  
    TabSpec specServices = tabHost.newTabSpec("Services").setIndicator("Services")  
                  .setContent(intent);  


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Inbox.class);  
    TabSpec specInbox = tabHost.newTabSpec("Inbox").setIndicator("Inbox")  
                  .setContent(intent);  


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, About.class);  
    TabSpec specAbout = tabHost.newTabSpec("About").setIndicator("About")  
                  .setContent(intent);  


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, More.class);  
    TabSpec specMore = tabHost.newTabSpec("More").setIndicator("More")  
                  .setContent(intent);  

    tabHost.addTab(specHelp); 
    tabHost.addTab(specServices); 
    tabHost.addTab(specInbox);
    tabHost.addTab(specAbout);        
    tabHost.addTab(specMore);
}
```

and a `tabcontroller.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:id="@android:id/tabhost" >

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">

       <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent">
       </FrameLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>

   </TabHost>
</merge>
```

What I want to do with that is to add that layout to multiple activities. When I try and add the layout I use `<include layout="@layout/tabcontroller"/>`. When I run the project my tab bar does not appear on the screen.

How can I add this tab bar to my activities? PS. `TabController.java` is not my main activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking a look at this tutorial over at : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107693/Tabbed-Applications-in-Android

One Thing i know ,maybe i am wrong, is that the Root Activity class must inherit TAbActivity and for you your TabController.java is not the main activity.

EDIT: THis is how i am getting Tabs which is not my Root Activity :

public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements OnTabChangeListener{

```
View v;
TabHost tabHost;    

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu_libraries, container, false);


     tabHost=(TabHost) v.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
     tabHost.setup();

     TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
     spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
     spec1.setIndicator("About",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android));

     TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
     spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
     spec2.setIndicator("Blog",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android));

     TabSpec spec3=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 3");
     spec3.setIndicator("Donate",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android));
     spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);

     TabSpec spec4=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 4");
     spec4.setIndicator("Explore",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android));
     spec4.setContent(R.id.tab4);

     tabHost.addTab(spec1);
     tabHost.addTab(spec2);
     tabHost.addTab(spec3);
     tabHost.addTab(spec4);

     return v;
}
```

As in the code above i am using fragments . So i inflate my VIew with the menu_libraries.xml which contains the tabs and the tabwidgets.
Inside the OncreateView function i am defining and inflating the tabs as well.
Not the best of answers but i guess you could try that.

Comment: My `HomeScreen` is my home page that does not have the tab bar so I have it extending Activity. If I make the `TabController` the Root Activity how can I get my `HomeScreen` to show up first and not show the tab bar?

Comment: So i am using fragments and in my app i am not even extending the TabActivity class. I have edited my previous comment so you can check that

Comment: Does that method go into every Activity I need the tab bar?

Comment: You can extend this class or you could use fragments or another method you could do is to create new intents on the click of a tab and display the content in the screen below the tab. Implementation part is upto you. First i would suggest you try to get the tabs in the Activity you are looking for first :)

Comment: I still cannot get the tabbar to show up in my activities. I have that code in my onCreate and it doesn't show up.

Comment: I have it showing up. Thanks for your help. Your way does work.